# Error when trying to call a function from another function in Python

Tags: python

I'm building a text-based game where you have the options to fight or run. It has a random element to it so you cannot just memorize the answers to gain a victory. My problem is I put the `random.randint` into a function so it could be "rolled" everytime it's called so I can adjust the percentage of success/failure (live/die) per question. I have it written where it works but the randomness is included in each question. I want to seperate that so I don't have to write it out each time.

```
import random

def q_1_1():
    option = [0,9]
    chance = random.randint(0,9)
    if chance <= 6:
        print('You won the fight')
    else:
        print('You lost the fight')
        quit()

def q_1_2():
    option = [0,9]
    chance = random.randint(0,9)
    if chance <= 6:
        print('You got away')
    else:
        print('You were captured')
        quit()


def user_input1():
    ui = input('fight or run? ').lower()
    if ui == 'fight':
        q_1_1()
        user_input1_2()

    if ui == 'run':
        q_1_2()
        user_input2()

user_input1()
```

`user_input2` just goes to next question and so on, but say after the first fight, the villain drops a piece of armor. I want to be able to adjust the percentage, which means I have to create 2 new functions for random and 2 new question functions. So I decided to clean it up and try to put the random in its own function so I can call it after each question.

```
import random

def roll():
    option = [0,9]
    chance = random.randint(0,9)
def win_f():
    print('You won the fight')
def win_r():
    print('You got away')
def lose_f():
    print('You lost the fight')
    quit()
def lose_r():
    print('You were captured')
    quit()


def user_input1():
    ui = input('Fight or Run? ').lower()
    if ui == 'fight':
        roll()
        if roll <= 6:
            win_f()
            user_input1_2()
        else:
            lose_f()

    if ui == 'run':
        roll()
        if roll <= 6:
            win_r()
            user_input2()
        else:
            lose_r()


user_input1()
```

Now this code is cleaner and will be easier to use, but for some reason I'm drawing a blank when trying to call the roll function.

> "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'"

is the error. How can I do this? I need to be able to re-roll the number every time the function is called. I cannot just have it roll once at startup.

Comment: sorry about the formatting, new here so learning how the code blocks work.

Comment: Looks like you mean `if roll() <= 6`. But your `roll` function needs to `return` the number it selects.

Comment: @khelwood yes. but i dont know how to do that, i tried adding in parenthesis but doesnt work.

Comment: @khelwood ahhh..I see. What if I put roll(chance) <= 6:    would that work? I'm not home rn so I can't try it. I also need it to roll a new number everytime it's called.

Comment: No, `roll(chance)` would not work. Your `roll()` function does not accept an argument.

Comment: @khelwood got it..posted answer thx my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

def roll_0():
    options = [0,9]
    chance = random.randint(0,9)
    return chance


def win_f_50_50():
    if roll_0() <= 4:
        print('You won the fight!')
        start_game()
    else:
        print('You lost the fight!')
        quit()

def win_r_50_50():
    if roll_0() <= 4:
        print('You got away!')
        start_game()
    else:
        print('You were captured!')
        quit()

def start_game():
    start = input('You must choose to "Fight" or "Run" ').lower()
    if start == 'fight':
        win_f_50_50()
    if start == 'run':
        win_r_50_50()

start_game()
```

Ok so i got it to work. you were right! and you even told me to use the return value and i still didnt get it. lol duh..i knew it was something simple i was missing thank you so much!!